# Inconsistent calculating in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate elapsed time and corrected time from a mysql table. The elapsed time is returned fine, but the corrected time is not always showing. Is this a timing issue? I am not making a variable and calling it in the same query. Can anybody tell me where to start on this?

```sql
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`startTid`) as 'elapsed', 
TIME_FORMAT((TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`startTid`) )* `rating` ,'%H:%i:%s') as 'korr_tid'
FROM faerder15_ 
WHERE `seilnummer` LIKE '$select' 
ORDER BY TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`startTid`)  )* `rating` ,'%H:%i:%s') DESC
```

The code is run on an rPi.

Here is an extract of the table:

```
id | seilnummer | type  | navn | skipper | seilforening | startKlasse | klasse | rating | startTid
==============================================================================================================
16 | NOR 12     | IF    | MAD  | Rob B   | B Yacht      | IF          | IF-båt | 0.0000 | 2015-04-15 13:30:00
92 | NOR 54     | Fenix | Kris | Joa B   | M Yacht      | T&H         |        | 0.8091 | 2015-04-15 00:00:00
```

Comment: Can you post the table declares and a few sample rows of data please? Is korr_tid the corrected elapsed time? However, are you intentionally trying to multiply a time by the rating in the ORDER BY clause (rather than multiplying the number of seconds by the rating and then converting that to a time)?

Comment: I assume you mean the 'Portsmouth Yardstick' [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portsmouth_Yardstick], but for clarity, can you define 'corrected time'?

Comment: Excactly, corrected time is elapsed time*rating. Elapsed time is hours between now and a timedate field called startTid.

Comment: Kickstart, I wanted to order by the corrected time as well, but this is not vital. I changed it to order by one of the other columns, but the result is still intermittent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the extract of the table but I found some inconsistencies. Can you please have a look at it again and fix the table?

Comment: You are right ByteHamster, there is a mismatch. The two columns 'klasseæ and startKlasse' are more or less duplicates, and are not relevant for the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for time multiplication

```
SEC_TO_TIME( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW(),`startTid`) )* `rating` )
```

Comment: Your method works in phpMyadmin (actually mine does too), but I'll check with php once I get back home. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Move the multiplication of the rating to further inside the brackets:-

```
SELECT *, 
        TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`startTid`) as 'elapsed', 
        TIME_FORMAT((TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`startTid`) * `rating` ),'%H:%i:%s') as 'korr_tid'
FROM faerder15_ 
WHERE `seilnummer` LIKE '$select' 
ORDER BY TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`startTid`) * `rating` ),'%H:%i:%s') DESC
```

I have tried to set up an SQL fiddle but struggling with an unrelated error at the moment so can't check this.

Comment: I'm not near my system now, and I will try this, but it does not make sense that the results should be intermittent due to bracketing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I agree normally (but I can't test it at the moment), unless it is down to how MySQL chooses to convert a formatted time to an number before multiplying it and whether the resulting value is a valid base for a date.